# A set of cards from which I can identify and number n

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, combinatorics

I am working with a collection of cards. On each card is written a set of numbers 1≤n≤N in ascending order.

When I arrange the cards in lexicographic order on the table, no two adjacent cards share a number.

The cards are designed so that when I pick a number r, select all the cards containing r, and sum the smallest numbers on each of those cards, I get the total r.

The idea is that I can ask a friend to choose a number 1≤n≤N, and ask them to identify the cards containing that number. From that information I can identify the number by doing a simple sum.

For example if N=4 the three sets {1,4},{2} and {3,4} could be written on the cards. They are in lexicographic order, no adjacent cards share a number, and any number 1≤n≤4 can be identified.

If you choose 1 for example, there is a single card lowest value 1. With 4 you pick up two cards values 1+3=4

Given N what is the smallest number of cards I need?

```
For 13 to 20 The answer is 6
     10 11 and 12  (1,4,6,9,12) (2,7,2) (3,4,11,12) (5,6,7) (8,9,2,11,12)   5
        9    (1,4,6,9) (2,7) (3,4) (5,6,7) (8,9)      5
        8   (1,4,6) (2,7) (3,4) (5,6,7) (8)           5
        7    (1,4,6) (2,7) (3,4) (5,6,7)              4
        6    (1,4,6) (2) (3,4) (5,6)                  4
        5     (1,4) (2) (3,4) (5)                     4
        4     (1,4) (2) (3,4)                         3
        3    (1) (2) (3)                              3
        2   (1) (2)                                   2
        1   (1)                                       1
```

How to find the minimum Numbers of set for a Number N.

Comment: Where is your attempt at an algorithm? This suspiciously looks like homework which does not always lead to great questions.

Comment: What does this mean: *On each card is written a set of numbers 1≤n≤N in ascending order.* What is `n` and what is `N`?